# STM32 PWM Setup - Bare Metal in CubeIDE

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, pwm, arm, timer

I have an [STM32L476 Discovery Board](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/32l476gdiscovery.html). I'm trying to generate a PWM signal on the GPIO pin PE14 using TIM1_CH4 using bare-metal in CubeIDE.

I have created a new project in Cube and have kept the default System Clock Configuration.
My aim is to have a duty cycle of 50%. I have prescaled by 79 in order to set the Timer Clock frequency at 1MHz.

I have gone through the [Datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32l476je.pdf), [Reference Manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00083560-stm32l47xxx-stm32l48xxx-stm32l49xxx-and-stm32l4axxx-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf), and [Timer Cookbook](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00236305-generalpurpose-timer-cookbook-for-stm32-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf) several times but for some reason, I can't get it to work. Is there something that I have overlooked in my code?

```
void intialize_gpioe(void){
    RCC->AHB2ENR |= RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOEEN;    // GPIOE clock enable
    GPIOE->MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODER14;  // Configure PE14 as Alternative Function.
    GPIOE->MODER |= ~GPIO_MODER_MODER14_1;
    GPIOE->AFR[1] &= ~GPIO_AFRH_AFRH6; // PE14 configured as AF1: TIM1_CH4
    GPIOE->AFR[1] |= 0x01000000;
}

void initalize_tim1(void){
    intialize_gpioe();
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_TIM1EN; // TIM1 timer clock enable
    TIM1->PSC = 79; // Set Prescaler to 1MHz
    TIM1->ARR = 100;
    TIM1-> CCR4 = 50;
    TIM1->CCMR2 &= ~TIM_CCMR2_CC4S; // CC4 channel is configured as output
    TIM1->CCER &= ~TIM_CCER_CC4P;   // Output Polarity set to Active High
    TIM1->CCMR2 &= ~TIM_CCMR2_OC4M; // Output Compare 4 Mode set as PWM Mode 1.
    TIM1->CCMR2 |= TIM_CCMR2_OC4M_1 | TIM_CCMR2_OC4M_2; // Output Compare 4 Mode set as PWM Mode 1.
    TIM1->CCMR2 |= TIM_CCMR2_OC4PE; // Enable the corresponding preload register
    TIM1->CCER |= TIM_CCER_CC4E; // Capture/Compare 4 Output Enable
    TIM1->EGR |= TIM_EGR_UG;    // Before starting the counter, you have to initialize all the registers
    TIM1->BDTR |= TIM_BDTR_MOE;
    TIM1->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN; // Start Timer
}
```

Comment: Can you describe "can't get it to work"? Does it fail to work? What's the error message? Does it crash at run-time? Does it behave differently than expected? If so, what do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by `bare-metal`?

Comment: you have to enable ARR preload in the CR1 register. it's a must for pwm generation according to the reference manual I read earlier. (I'm answering based on another model)

Comment: @Codo No errors in the code. But no signal appears on the pin. I know the pin works because I have a separate project to specifically test the pwm on this pin using HAL.

Comment: @jsotola In my case, bare-metal would be register configuration with bitmasking without HAL functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GPIO Alternative function configuration is incorrect:

```
GPIOE->MODER |= ~GPIO_MODER_MODER14_1;
```

The correct configuration is:

```
GPIOE->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER14_1;
```